# Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context problem

Tags: xcode

I am trying to make a quiz app and I have a this error message

Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context
it is on this line if counter == 1 && (AnswerField!.text != nil) == "because the gods were very powerful" on the ".text" part

```
@IBOutlet weak var SeeScore: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var AnswerField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!

var counter = 0
var score = 0


@IBAction func DoneQuestion(_ sender: Any) {
counter += 1
    if counter == 10 {
        SeeScore.isHidden = false
    }
    if counter == 1 && (AnswerField!.text != nil) == "because the gods were very powerful" {

    }
}
```

Thanks and I hope you can fix this!

Answer (score 0):

```
(AnswerField!.text != nil) == "because the gods were very powerful"
```

This expression evaluates to `Bool == String` which is not what I think you mean. It's not what what you're trying to do here, but this is where your code is incorrect.